# Why Table Storage support is no included the new new Azure ADK for JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, sdk, azure-table-storage

Microsft released [azure-sdk-for-js](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/tree/master/sdk/storage) a long time back but still, there is no plan to support Table Storage. The only option for Table storage from NodeJS is legacy [azure-storage-node](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node). Is Microsoft trying to retire Table Storage in long term?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Accoring to [this update on azure storage table sdk seems not supported #5655](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/issues/5655#issuecomment-690519979), there is now an official [**azure-sdk-for-js for data-tables**](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/tree/main/sdk/tables/data-tables) which you can install like this:

```sh
npm install @azure/data-tables
```